# How to change this mongo query to return "00:00" if $match condition does not satisfy in aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, match, aggregate

Consider I have a timesheets collection like this:

```
[
  {
     _id: 1,
     createdBy: "John",
     duration: "00:30"
  },
  {
     _id: 2,
     createdBy: "John",
     duration: "01:30"
  },
  {
     _id: 3,
     createdBy: "Mark",
     duration: "00:30"
  },
]
```

My input is an array of usernames:

```
["John", "Mark", "Rikio"]
```

I want to use mongodb aggregate to calculate the total duration of timesheets for each user in the usernames array and If there are no timesheets found, it should return duration: "00:00". For example, it should return:

```
[
   {createdBy: "John", totalDuration: "02:00"}, 
   {createdBy: "Mark", totalDuration: "00:30"}, 
   {createdBy: "Rikio", totalDuration: "00:00"}
]
```

However, when I use $match query, if there are no timesheets it will not return anything so I don't know which user does not have the timesheets and return "00:00" for them.

Comment: there is no straight way to do in query, You have to do it in client side after query in JS/NodeJS logic.

Comment: @turivishal I totally agree with you. It's better to do it in client side.

Comment: @turivishal Could you guys please elaborate more on how should I handle it on the client-side. I also tried to do this with for loop but the performance of the server will be really slow if the array of usernames increases.

Comment: @AnhNgô You can either query like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/23UwKeRP77a) or [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/emwktYs9YL4) first. Make sure to minimize your data return from database.

Comment: @YuTing I also found a problem with this query, what if $match does not find anything and return [], so the query will not work. Do you have any ideas for this?

Comment: I see, you are right. Maybe you should insert a default document and always match it, then remove it in the final level of aggregate. Or you can only do it in client side like @turivishal said. do [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/emwktYs9YL4) first, and then do the rest in client side.

Comment: @YuTing Thank you so much for helping me to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with @turivishal , but still can make it through mongo query with an ugly one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $set: {
      minutes: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            time: {
              $split: [
                "$duration",
                ":"
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            "$add": [
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  {
                    $toInt: {
                      $first: "$$time"
                    }
                  },
                  60
                ]
              },
              {
                $toInt: {
                  $last: "$$time"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$createdBy",
      "totalMinutes": {
        "$sum": "$minutes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "docs": {
        $map: {
          "input": [
            "John",
            "Mark",
            "Rikio"
          ],
          "as": "name",
          "in": {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                findName: {
                  "$first": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$docs",
                      "as": "d",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$$d._id",
                          "$$name"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              in: {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": "$$findName",
                  "then": "$$findName",
                  "else": {
                    _id: "$$name",
                    totalMinutes: 0
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": "$docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "hours": {
        $floor: {
          "$divide": [
            "$totalMinutes",
            60
          ]
        }
      },
      "minutes": {
        "$mod": [
          "$totalMinutes",
          60
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "hours": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lt": [
              "$hours",
              10
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$concat": [
              "0",
              {
                "$toString": "$hours"
              }
            ]
          },
          "else": {
            "$toString": "$hours"
          }
        }
      },
      "minutes": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lt": [
              "$minutes",
              10
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$concat": [
              "0",
              {
                "$toString": "$minutes"
              }
            ]
          },
          "else": {
            "$toString": "$minutes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      duration: {
        "$concat": [
          "$hours",
          ":",
          "$minutes"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x77TsxoWLVM)